# How to implement an interface with multiple anonymous functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to implement interface shown below in typescript

```
interface A{
  (message: string, callback: CustomCallBackFunction): void;
  (message: string, meta: any, callback: CustomCallBackFunction): void;
  (message: string, ...meta: any[]): void;
  (message: any): void;
  (infoObject: object): void;
}
```

here CustomCallBackFunction defintion

```
type CustomCallBackFunction= (error?: any, level?: string, message?: string, meta?: any) => void;
```

I am unable to implement the interface with class. Any idea how to do this.

This is for method overloading
For example, i have a class B with a variable of type A with implementation referring to all other options.

```
class B {
public c: A
}
```

Then i can call

```
const b =new B();
b.c(message,callback);
b.c(message,meta,callback);
b.c(message,meta);
b.c(infoObject);
```

Comment: Interesting question, I played a bit around and didn't find a good solution for implementing anonymous functions via interfaces. Why exactly do they need to be anonymous?

Comment: What is the actual issue/error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the only way to implement this interface to to make all arguments `any`.

This interface is much like [function overloads.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) Which means the implementation function must take an argument that is a union of all possibilities of the argument at that position.

1. The first argument is `string`, `string`, `string`, `any` or `object`. So the type is `string | object | any`, which simplifies to just `any` since `any` includes the other possibilities.
2. The second argument is `CustomCallBackFunction | any | undefined`, which again is `any`
3. The third argument could be `CustomCallBackFunction` or the second item of `...meta: any[]`, so again, that one is `any`.

---

So, given that all arguments must be of type `any`, *and* there may any number of arguments, I think the only implementation signature that will work is:

```
const fn: A = (...args: any[]) => {}
```

You'd then have to test the type of each argument yourself and figure out what the meaning of each one is and which call signature was used. And yeah, that's gonna suck.

```
const fn: A = (...args: any[]) => {
    if (args.length === 2 && typeof args[0] === 'string' && typeof args[1] === 'function') {
        // (message: string, callback: CustomCallBackFunction): void;
        const [message, callback] = args as [string, CustomCallBackFunction]
    } else if (args.length === 3 && typeof args[0] === 'string' && !Array.isArray(args[1]) && typeof args[2] === 'function') {
        // (message: string, meta: any, callback: CustomCallBackFunction): void;
        const [message, meta, callback] = args as [string, any, CustomCallBackFunction]
    } else {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYwIYBssCEMDGA1gGJwB2BwAlsuVALxQAUEATm8mwPwBcUGciAA0ULBABuELHyhI21cgHNRqCAgQYlEWfMUqoa4BlmCQASkYA+KBOTUAJgG4AUC8XB2AM0LQAglAA3i5QLGoaWhD8esqiBNhYAEaERPzwSGiYOPjEZJQ0dOb8do6uoczhmtrRwAqxhhDG-GZxCcnEaYgo6Ak5pBRUtORFtvbOIWHqVVFytfqiAHRLRhjNQgDaALojJePllZFrFsVjZSyKXsgA8okAVhBU-Mh3D8A7py4Avm4EdEhQXnI-ACTGYSwWGDYSgQRy2lgYNmCoVC1C8LEh0IW4mUwAAFowGEwAExQABkpKgoEgyDRGIQ6wADJsCUwAOQxJSsskUqkQGkCKH0gCMzMJbK8AwK5FZliRyPlAHoFZMItVZnUDPEcO1UrAupleik8oNCidShN5aFfuR-usDtpWtqUqKBdCBAgoOsOaJ0t0sngjZKhpsLVBPlBpAhoKj0YKsRAcfixVAAMzcyngPm0wWM0WEqDsubKLnkqAAQj8HAwIAW1AQlbY1eYdPWIsspd5-JbRLz4qDdBlQVDiuVFSmh3V8waTQEQkdSRSnQyPWygfyQ3e5styOttvtEFUjQw851Lrp7s93tnIj1y-9fWNUpD8vDkegcu3SojwAI4ND30+IA)

Comment: Every function that has a compatible set of call signatures implements the interface. Implementation is not a function of syntax such as of a type annotation or the implements keyword. It is implicit because the language is structurally typed not nominally typed. Therefore, I think this is a poor solution because it reduces type safety in order to declare types and use explicit type annotations, a bad trade.